# Couldn't use generator and task in clion on mac

Tags: c++, clion, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have such code:

```
generator<int> range(int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        co_yield start;
        start++;
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    for (auto n: range(0, 10)) {
        cout << n << ' ';
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get an error:

```
error: no template named 'generator'; did you mean 'iterator'?
```

I have a similar error with the task. Is it a problem with the support of c++20? How to fix?

Comment: I assume the compiler is clang. Clang's support of coroutines is partial atm.

Comment: There is no such thing in C++20, It is still in the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2168r3.pdf) stage, the workaround is to use a third-party library such as [cppcoro's generator implementation](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/generator.hpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 康桓瑋 said, it is still in the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2168r3.pdf) stage, the workaround is to use a third-party library such as [cppcoro's generator implementation](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/generator.hpp).

Comment: When copying a comment verbatim into your answer, you need to provide attribution. Also, why didn't you add the link to the proposal as well?